# Can i reload div automaticly without click events?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

i want to togle between 2 carts icon,one display when the cart is empty the second when  is not,

```html
<div id="div-icon-cart">
        <span class="tools-icon">



        <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) { ?>
                                

    <img  decoding="async" src="https://txxxx.com/uploads/cart.svg" class="custom-icon" alt="" height="20.738" width="17.626">      
                <?php } else{ ?>


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

but the problem is that the cart icon doesn't change immediately,i need to refrech the page to upload cart icon.
for that i tried to reload div which contains my cart icon

```js
    $document.ready(function(){
        $('#div-icon-cart').load();
        setInterval{fonction(){
            $('#div-icon-cart').load();
        },3000};
    });
```

but doesn't work and i don't know why.i would be grateful for any help

NB:

- i cant trriger an event like onClick.
- the right solution for me is to reload div automaticly

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the problem might just be some typos:

- `$document` should be `$(document)`
- `{fonction` should be `(function`
- `},3000};` should be `},3000);`
- there seems to be something wrong with `.load()`, not sure exactly

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#div-icon-cart').load();
  setInterval(function() {
    $('#div-icon-cart').load();
  }, 3000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="div-icon-cart">
        <span class="tools-icon">



        <?php if ( ! WC()->cart->is_empty() ) { ?>
                                

    <img  decoding="async" src="https://txxxx.com/uploads/cart.svg" class="custom-icon" alt="" height="20.738" width="17.626">      
                <?php } else{ ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your help i changed my cod ,but it still doesn't work i added alert just to see if script is working but doesn't display

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div-icon-cart').load();
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#div-icon-cart').load();
        },3000);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code.

Please change your code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div-icon-cart').load();
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#div-icon-cart').load();
        },3000);
  });
```

Comment: i change my cod ,but it still doesn't work i added alert just to see if script is working but doesn't display

Answer (score 0):

i tried this code

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      
      setInterval(function() {
      
         alert('tstt');
        $('#div-cartIcon').load();

      }, 3000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the alert show up, but i when i make it after div Load doesn't diplay

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      setInterval(function() {
        $('#div-cartIcon').load();
        
        alert('tstt');


      }, 3000);
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

if anyone could explain why  $('#div-cartIcon').load(); doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

Please replace jquery part to this.

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#div-icon-cart').load();
        setInterval(function(){
            $('#div-icon-cart').load();
        },3000);
  });
```